# javascript - replacing text not between in attributes

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to replace text inside an HTML string with Javascript.
The tricky part is that I need to replace the text only if it isn't inside a tag (meaning it's not part of an attribute):

```
var html_str = '<div>hi blah blah<img src="img.jpg" alt="say hi" /><a href="link_hi.php">hi!</a></div>';
```

In this example, after I do `html_str.replace("hi","hello");` I want to replace only the text inside the `div` and `a` tags, avoiding the `<img alt=".."` or the `href="...`.

Some more info:

1. `html_str = document.body.innerHTML;`, therefore the elements are unknown. The example above is only an example.
2. Regex are more than welcome.
3. The `hi` and `hello` values are inside varaibles, meaning the actual replace is like so: `html_str.replace(var1,var2);`

The REAL code is this:

```
var html_str = document.body.innerHTML;
var replaced_txt = "hi";
var replace_with = "hello";
var replaced_html = html_str.replace(replaced_txt,replace_with);
```

I hope I explained myself well. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This maybe?

```
var obj = {'hi':'hello','o':'*','e':'3','ht':'HT','javascrpit':'js','ask':'ASK','welcome':'what\'s up'}; // This may contain a lot more data

(function helper(parent, replacements) {
  [].slice.call(parent.childNodes, 0).forEach(function (child) {
    if (child.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      for (var from in replacements) {
        child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.replace(from, replacements[from]);
      }
    }
    else {
      helper(child, replacements);
    }
  });
}(document.body, obj));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G8fYq/4/  (*uses document.body directly*)

If you want to make the changes visible immediately then you could also pass `document.body` and forget about the whole `container` stuff.

*Update to allow for multiple replacements in one run.*

---

You could also try *XPath* in javascript, though the following solution will not work in IE.

```
var
  replacements = {'hi':'hello','o':'*','e':'3','ht':'HT','javascrpit':'js','ask':'ASK','welcome':'what\'s up'},
  elements = document.evaluate('//text()', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null),
  i = 0,
  textNode, from;

for (; i < elements.snapshotLength; i += 1) {
  textNode = elements.snapshotItem(i);

  for (from in replacements) {
    if (replacements.hasOwnProperty(from)) {
      textNode.nodeValue = textNode.nodeValue.replace(from, replacements[from]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Phoenix out of curiosity, why not?

Comment: It just didn't work. Actually I hoped that this solution would work, it suites my code better. I need to make changes to the HTML text without making any 'damage' on the tags and that often happens with regex.

Comment: @Phoenix so why just not say how it is not working? That's how it is usually done arround here ;)

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried all the responses and just checked the one that worked almost 'on the box'. I think the problem with your solution is the amount of loops that need to be done. The `replace_txt` and `replace_with` come from a JSON that may contain a lot of data. see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/G8fYq/5/

Comment: @Phoenix Ah, I see your problem. Of course it's a lot of wasted cpu-power to traverse the whole document tree for every replacement. I'd suggest traversing only once, but replacing multiple times on every found text-node. I updated the code accordingly, have a look. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. Both of your solutions worked for me. Definitely  yours is the best answer! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible to use this simple regex negative lookahead:

```
(?![^<>]*>)
```

Just add it to your match pattern and it will exclude any content as attributes in tags. Here is an example:
[Javascript regex: Find all URLs outside <a> tags - Nested Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553751/javascript-regex-find-all-urls-outside-a-tags-nested-tags)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this, but regexp and HTML are not friends:

```
var str = '<div>hi blah blah<img src="img.jpg" alt="say hi" /><a href="link_hi.php">hi!</a></div>',
    rx = new RegExp('(\>[^\>]*)' + 'hi' + '([^\>=]*\<)', 'g');

str = str.replace(rx, '$1hello$2');
```

Comment: Thank you. I needed to remove the `\` before the `>` but worked well for me.