# Javascript regex: Find all URLs outside <a> tags - Nested Tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex, hyperlink, nested

I have built this regex code:

```
((https?|ftps?):\/\/[^"<\s]+)(?![^<>]*?>|[^<>]*?<\/)
```

The first group captures all links in HTML and the second is a negative lookahead to exclude any parts inside tags as attributes and any parts inside tags as content.

I would like that only `<a>` tags are excluded - so the solution could be to modify only the last term to:

```
[^<>]*?<\/a>
```

But now there will be a problem if I have nested tags, for example, `<b></b>` inside `<a>`.

Here is the example I am working on: https://regex101.com/r/lM3hC5/6 (should be 10 matches).

Negative lookahead is still tricky for me. I thought that the following should work but it isn't:

```
(?!<a.+?<\/a>)
```

https://regex101.com/r/hT1cG5/1

These are the last discussions that helped me:

- [Regex replace text outside html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621568/regex-replace-text-outside-html-tags)
- [Regex replace text but exclude when text is between specific tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493128/regex-replace-text-but-exclude-when-text-is-between-specific-tag)

Comment: Isn't that problem enough serious to stop relying on regex for extracting texts from the HTML? Use a DOM parser.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What do you mean *DOM parser* exactly? Something like this? http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: I am just wondering if that would be possible since for this purpose my code is quite neat and simple with regex.

Comment: @user2943191 I read somewhere using regex should be last option ..

Comment: Here is a possible [DOM based solution](https://jsfiddle.net/4ufuLpcu/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out that probably the best solution is the following:

```
((https?|ftps?):\/\/[^"<\s]+)(?![^<>]*>|[^"]*?<\/a)
```

Looks like that the negative lookahead is working properly only if it starts with [quantifiers](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) and not strings. For such a case, it follows that practically we can do backtracks only.

Again, we just want to make sure that nothing inside HTML tags as attributes is messed up. Then we do a backtrack starting from `</a` up to the first `"` symbol (as it is not a valid URL symbol but `<>` symbols are present with nested tags).

Now also nested tags inside `<a>` tags are found properly. Of course, the code is not perfect but it should work with almost any simple HTML markup. Just you may need to be a bit careful with:

- placing quotes within `<a>` tags;
- do not use this algorithm on `<a>` tags without any attribute ([placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19167175/2943191));
- as well as you may need to avoid using multiple nested tags/lines unless the URL inside `<a>` tag is after any double quote.

Here is a very good and messy example (the last match should not be found but it is):

https://regex101.com/r/pC0jR7/2

It is a pity that this lookahead does not work: `(?!<a.*?<\/a>)`

Comment: Maybe someone could find a better way to optimize this code.