# Javascript regex: Find all URLs optimization

Tags: javascript, html, regex, hyperlink, multipart-alternative

This question is a follow-up for the following post:
[Javascript regex: Find all URLs outside <a> tags - Nested Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553751/javascript-regex-find-all-urls-outside-a-tags-nested-tags)

I discovered that the code:

```
\b((https?|ftps?):\/\/[^"<\s]+)(?![^<>]*>|[^"]*?<\/a)
```

is extremely inefficient compared to executing it separately for `http` and `ftp` part like this:

```
\b(https?:\/\/[^"<\s]+)(?![^<>]*>|[^"]*?<\/a)
```

and

```
\b(ftps?:\/\/[^"<\s]+)(?![^<>]*>|[^"]*?<\/a)
```

Here are examples at regex101.com:

- 1st method - [6395 steps](https://regex101.com/r/aM0oM3/1)
- 2nd method - [3393 steps](https://regex101.com/r/aM0oM3/2) + [863 steps](https://regex101.com/r/aM0oM3/3)

However, in one of my HTML page these codes compares as **85628** steps vs. **7258 + 795** steps, that is quite insane.

As far as I have seen, using [(x|y)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_xy.asp) pattern reduces the execution length but here probably for a strange reason it is otherwise.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about the last link in your sample data? It is wihtin `<a`...`</a>`. However, you can put the lookahead after a fixed part of your regex to reduce steps. Try [`\b(?:htt|ft)ps?:\/\/(?![^<>]*>|[^"]*?<\/a)[^"<\s]+`](https://regex101.com/r/tZ1yY2/1). The better way would be to use [this trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick) for matching what you don't want but capture what you need: [`<a\s[\s\S]*?<\/a>|<[^>]+>|\b((?:htt|ft)ps?:\/\/[^"<\s]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/tZ1yY2/2). Btw, Javascript regex does not support Atomic Groups.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are a victim of [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

This regex does the trick in just 3492 steps:

```
\b(?>(https?|ftps?):\/\/[^"<\s]+)(?![^<>]*>|[^"]*?<\/a)
```

All I have done is made the first group an [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html), causing the engine to discard all backtracking options once it's matched it.

That's correct in your case: you can think of it now as two parts, "find a URL" then "Use the negative lookahead to decide if we want to keep it". Your original regex would, when the lookahead failed, proceed to backtrack into the url-matching expression. The `[^"<\s]+` block would yield some symbols, then it would try the lookahead again, then yield some more symbols, and try again, and so on...

The reason the addition of the `https?|ftps?` part made it so much worse was that this provides an extra source of backtracking (losing the optional s) in a way that allows all the later backtracking to happen all over again.

You know that regex101.com has a "regex debugger" option on the toolbar on the left? If you use that, it explains *how* your regex matches, so you can (as I just did) figure out where the crazy backtracking is.

Bonus edit: A further improved one that only takes 3185 steps:

```
\b(?>ht|f)tps?:\/\/(?>[^"<\s]+)(?![^<>]+>|[^"]*?<\/a)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was aware of the catastrophic backtracking that I also found with the help of debugger but couldn't solve it.

Comment: The trick is to figure out which parts of your regex can survive becoming atomic like this. Your example is an easy one, but many regexes require lots of backtracking to work right. Sometimes it's possible to rejig the regex a bit to make more amenable to this trick.

Answer (score 0):

if you looking for find all links  in document than solution is this.
it return an array

```js
document.anchors
```

Comment: As the previous post explains - I want to find all URLs that are outside anchor (<a>) tags.